# Downlading a transformed image using the browser but I'm getting the original one instead of the transformed one

Tags: html, css, image

Probably a silly question, but not sure if it's possible to achieve it. I have an image in a page that uses the CSS style transform: scale(-1,1) then mirroring the original image. What I need is to download the mirrored image, I mean, the one that is in the transformed state. But when I download the image I'm getting the original one, so, this one is not scaled. Is there any way by only having the page, to download the image in the CSS state that I'm seeing it?

I know there are other tools, that I can use to mirror the original image. Still, my question here is if from only the browser as is, without any extensions or third-party libraries, may I download the image transformed?

Comment: CSS doesn't modify the image, it just describes how the browser would display the image.  If you want to produce a modified copy of the image, you'd need a tool which does that.

Comment: I would look into loading images into the canvas via javascript, modifying it, then saving it.

Comment: If you are using chrome you could look into `Capture node screenshot`. It includes all CSS. Without using extensions you would need to open the inspection tool and right click on the element to do so however.

Comment: @SyndRain thanks, that makes my day :D. I did not know about this functionality built-in in the browser. Create the answer if You want the points :D

Comment: Of note .. you could use Javascript to do this though, a button that you clicked that downloads the image when you click the button as the image is displayed.  That way it works regardless of browser type (short of ancient ones).

Comment: @easleyfixed How would you do that with JavaScript? I couldn't figure it out without using Chrome extension apis. (`puppeteer`)

Comment: Indeed, short of the user turning off javascript it could be an ideal solution, but if you are interested I could type something up.  But seems you already have an accepted answer so perhaps I'll hold off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using chrome you could look into [Capture node screenshot](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/dom#screenshot). This is a built in feature without any extensions and applies CSS properties. Open the inspection tool and right click on the element to do so. (One shortcut to find the element in the inspection tool is to right click on the image and click `inspect`.)

Note that if the transforms are applied to a div wrapper of the image, you could capture the node screenshot for that div.

[image]